# Android iTextPdf utf-8 not working

Tags: android, itextpdf

I am trying to get font with UTF-8, but no success. Currently i use:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(new String("čšđćž".getBytes("UTF-8")), new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 14)));
```

I get only: šž, so it is font problem?

Comment: Yes, it's a font problem. `TIMES_ROMAN` doesn't support the characters you need. You have to use a different font as explained in the [http://developers.itextpdf.com/](official documentation). Please read the answer to the question [How to use Cyrillic characters in a PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-use-cyrillic-characters-pdf)

Comment: In addition to @Bruno's correct analysis, the construct `new String("čšđćž".getBytes("UTF-8"))` is weird, depending on the environment it either is a NOOP or an error source. Ah, and the documentation link should have looked like this:  [official documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/).

Comment: I solved it like this:
 BaseFont courier = BaseFont.createFont("assets/fonts/roboto.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
                Font fontNormal = new Font(courier, 12, Font.NORMAL);
and used also XMLWorkerHelper for HTML